# How to swap first div with last div on mobile version?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have divs as follows.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12" id="first-row"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-12" id="second-row"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-12" id="third-row"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-12" id="fourth-row"></div>
</div>
```

How can i swap first-row div with fourth-row div on mobile devices? Is it possible to do with just css? What could be best stragety to achieve this, I can do this with javascript, but wanted to know whether it is possible with just css. I am using bootstrap 3

Expected result on mobile

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" id="fourth-row"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12" id="second-row"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12" id="third-row"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12" id="first-row"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: For a purely CSS way, you could use two divs and the bootstrap classes .hidden-lg, .hidden-md, ... and .visible-sm, .visible-xs. The encompassing divs can use these. The flexbox method is probably much better, though.

Comment: did you consider using bootstrap-4 ? **You could give a quick try swapping the library** : https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css .. Example from your code and bootstrap-4 :  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/oeQWeO swap easy made from a mediaquerie and `order` : `@media screen and (max-width : 600px) {  
  .row > :first-of-type{order:1;}
  .row > :last-of-type {order:-1;}  
}`  . **I only make a comment since you said using bootstrap 3 ;), but can be turned into an answer if you wish**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `flexbox` on the `row`, you can use the [**`order`**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_order.asp) property to do this for you. (you can use *media queries* for adding `display: flex` to *target* mobile devices)

See how the positions of `fourth-row` and `first-row` are swapped in the demo below:

```css
div.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

[id$='-row'] {
  order: 2;
}
#first-row {
  order: 3;
}
#fourth-row {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12" id="first-row">1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12" id="second-row">2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12" id="third-row">3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12" id="fourth-row">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Flex property to swap elements. Here is an article about it [Reverse Elements Order](https://davidwalsh.name/css-reverse).

Unable to demonstrate the mobile only part, so please use the below CSS.

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
    .row { display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; }
}
```

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
 $('.row').toggleClass('row-reverse');
})
```

```css
.row-reverse { display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12" id="first-row">first</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12" id="second-row">second</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12" id="third-row">third</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12" id="fourth-row">fourth</div>
</div>
<button>reverse/unreverse</button>
```

Comment: @kukkuz the OP says  `How can i swap first-row div with fourth-row div on mobile devices?` let me change that in my answer thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the look in different screen sizes, you can use default Bootstrap grid ordering:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-column-ordering

Might be easier to see the responsive result here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vJQmXq

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-md-push-9" id="fourth-row">4</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3" id="second-row">2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3" id="third-row">3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-md-pull-9" id="first-row">1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution using `jQuery` https://jsfiddle.net/68bfxozm/1/

```js
var updateDivOrder = function() {
  if($(document).width() < 500){
    var first = $('#first-row').clone();
    var last = $('#fourth-row').clone();
    $('.row div').first().remove();
    $('.row div').last().remove();

    $('.row div').first().before(last);
    $('.row div').last().after(first);
  } else {
    var first = $('#first-row').clone();
    var last = $('#fourth-row').clone();
    $('.row div').first().remove();
    $('.row div').last().remove();

    $('.row div').first().before(first);
    $('.row div').last().after(last);
  }
}

updateDivOrder();

$(window).resize(updateDivOrder);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12" id="first-row">1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12" id="second-row">2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12" id="third-row">3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12" id="fourth-row">4</div>
</div>
```

My assumption is `mobile width` will be less than **500px**.

Hope this will help you.